# when comparing two entities how to get rid of the "II" symbol in slots upon displaying of response?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I tried doing this

[image]

It does it's function as an or
but when I try displaying the data it also shows the "||" along with it

[image]

Can someone please help me on how to solve this the right way. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of || in the "Check for"? is that really working as intended by you?

Comment: I wanted to get another value in a different entity so I thought this would be the way. And yes it actually worked it just displayed the || along with it. I wanted to know how to remove it upon display.

Comment: Have you tried using an actual OR and spaces? Personally, I would use two variables (slots) and then only combine it in the answer

Comment: I also tried using OR and adding spaces and nothing changed for me.

Comment: See my recommendation as answer below: Use two variables and combine them for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two variables, one for each entity. Later, in the response, I would then combine the two variables with an OR. It is a cleaner design and you could reuse the variable values in other places, too.